how to set custom view mode for add/edit node for content type?
I have a content type Teams, and I have created 'Profile' view mode for rendering the data.
I need to set the 'Profile' view mode instead of Default view mode for add or edit node of this content type.

How should we achieve this scenario.
Thanks in advance,

The question is that you want to use a view display mode as a form display mode. Is that correct?

yes, thats correct

You can't. See the answer below.

Entities have two distinct "Display modes":

View mode - this controls the rendering of an entity, usually an HTML wrapper or two, and then a list of rendered fields in whatever order. You can think of this as the "output" mode.
Form mode - this controls the rendering of an entity form; which widgets a particular fields uses, the settings for the widget, and so on. This is the "input" mode.

These two concepts aren't interchangeable. The only built-in customisation available for entity forms are Form modes. You won't be able to use your "Profile" View mode to affect the entity form, because the entity form is rendering widgets, not fields. As such it can only be customised with a Form mode.
You can manage your available form modes under Admin -> Structure -> Display modes -> Form modes.
